# How to to add remarks when casting a reopen vote

Tags: discussion, questions, vote-to-reopen

I just cast my first reopen vote, and I expected to be able to explain why I was doing so (the "Learn more" link explicitly asks for comments). However, I didn't see any possibilities to add some comments or whatever. Did I miss something?

The question I voted to reopen was [regex for find flag without care about order in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78149075/regex-for-find-flag-without-care-about-order-in-java), and, however naive, it was a reasonable question, and the asker's intent seemed clear. And in the end, a good answer may be useful to other inexperienced users.

Comment: Which '"Learn more" link' are you referring to?

Comment: You mean other than the "Add a comment" link underneath the question?

Comment: Personally I wouldn't recommend reopening that specific post. It's a duplicate.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat *if* OP means to parse the command line, yes. It wasn't clear to me that this is the case, because the only real evidence for that is the format of the input.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I believe some if not all of those answers should be able to be applied to strings as well.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Fair enough. I see the reasoning now.

Comment: Questions are not generally reopened if they should be closed for another reason. Maybe 15 years ago that would have been done, but nowadays there is too much incoming material which also needs to be sorted to spend that amount of effort on it.

Comment: It's funny how the focus seems to be on the linked question (which is now deleted) rather than the actual question. Should probably not have linked the question at all...

Comment: @Cuzy Correcting misconceptions and filling in gaps in knowledge simply takes precedence. As it should.

Answer (score 6):

> However I didn't see any possibilities to add some comments or whatever. Did I miss something?

I'm pretty sure you're expected to comment *on the question*. After all, that's where comments would appear that could actually be seen by others. There aren't comments specifically attached to the reopen vote, because there isn't a place in the UI that displays individual votes with their metadata.

> and I think that, however naive, it is a reasonable question, and the OP's intent seems clear to me.

**It really isn't.** Not at all.

What does "get information" entail?

Suppose the input is `data -fn firstname -ln lastname -e email -ph phonenumber`, or `data -ln lastname -e email -ph phonenumber -fn firstname`, or `data -fn firstname -e email -ln lastname -ph phonenumber`. What I understood from the question is that the output should be the same for all of these inputs. But this tells me exactly nothing about *what that output should be*. Should it be a sequence of strings? A mapping from strings like `-ln` to strings like `lastname`? An instance of some class (which one)? Something else?

Further, is this a string that the program will process? Or is it a command line that will be used to run the program? Or something else? If it's a command line, then this is [already handled by a common duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367706/how-do-i-parse-command-line-arguments-in-java) (with a few dozen inbound links already).

Further, the question mentions the possibility of using regular expressions, but I have absolutely no idea how OP intends to apply them here or why OP thinks they might relevant to solving the problem.

Further, the close votes came from one of the biggest names in both the [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) and [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) tags on the site, and a moderator with a 14-year-old account. Both have six-digit reputation totals and have definitely seen a few things. And all of this is happening after several attempts to fix the question, including some formatting and copyediting assistance from the moderator in question.

My experience has been that, if anything, high-rep users are too eager to keep questions open (they got the rep mostly by writing answers, after all, and closing a question prevents answers, so the reputation system creates a conflict of interest). In conclusion: it is extremely unlikely that you will change anyone's mind here.

Comment: i mean, to be fair, it is a regex question, and people on meta for some reason have a thing for keeping regex questions open.

Comment: @KevinB it still feels difficult to characterize what is actually wrong with so many of those questions. It seems to boil down to "regex is its own programming language and this is a debugging request or a write-the-code request, and thus Needs More Focus"; but there seems to be a ton of push-back on that reasoning.

Comment: More broadly, eh, it seems clear _enough_; the real problem is that it's a duplicate. It's parsing command-line flags (and asks "Is regex the best way to solve this?", to which the answer is "no"). If they're coming directly from the command line, which seems overwhelmingly likely, then the duplicate applies directly. If they're in string form and there can't be spaces because this is a toy problem (actual names can, of course have spaces), split the string on spaces and then apply the dupe. If they're in string form and they actually need to parse from _that_, then they can clarify via edit.

Comment: Mm, fair enough. The question is different in Java vs Python, I guess, in that Java's entry point has a `String[]` passed in explicitly as a parameter, and thus any command-line-argument-handling library would just expect a `String[]` input by default; whereas in Python you most likely need to know a little about `sys.argv`.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel most of the well known packages that support command line parsing in Python also allow you specify a list of strings. For example [here's how you can do it with argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#parsing-arguments)

Comment: Ok, I can see what you mean. In a sense, however, all basic questions about regex boil down to "I don't understand how they work" and so are kind of duplicates of each other. In this case the asker seemed to not even realize that they didn't need 24 different expressions, so I thought a clarification about that would have been useful to them, and probably to other beginners. Just that.

Comment: @gimix you're not wrong, certain tags just work different and are just streams of "duplicate but the devil is in the details" questions. Regex, SQL, CSS, those kind of things. Just one dupe after another and the people who curate such questions tend to take it into account. That's the consequence of allowing topics which are not really programming problems, IMO. You'd also need different sets of rules, but we have just the one set which are more designed for C/C++ questions.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I know they *allow* it, but getting information from the command line is still fundamentally different in Python because it comes from `sys.argv` rather than from an argument that was passed to your code explicitly.